# Why is the following map injective

Tags: commutative-algebra

I just have a quick question consider the map:
$$\psi : \mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y - x^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[t]$$
$$x \mapsto t$$
$$y \mapsto t^2$$

I want to check that this map is injective. In particular, I showed that it has inverse map. I interested to know why is the kernel of the map above trivial? The way I did that was I showed it is the pull-back of a map between varieties which is injective. Is it possible to do that more directly ?

Comment: In fact, it's an isomorphism, with inverse being the homomorphism such that $t \mapsto x$.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to understand how can we show that kernel of $\psi$ is trivial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\psi$ is already an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras:

Let $\varphi \colon \mathbb{C}[t] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y - x^2)$ be the unique homomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with $\varphi(t) = \overline{x}$.
Then
$$
\psi(\varphi(t))
= \psi(\overline{x})
= t
$$
and thus $\psi \varphi = \operatorname{id}$, and similarly
$$
\varphi(\psi(\overline{x}))
= \varphi(t)
= \overline{x}
$$
and
$$
\varphi(\psi(\overline{y}))
= \varphi(t^2)
= \overline{x^2}
= \overline{y}
$$
and thus $\varphi \psi = \operatorname{id}$.

Note that this corresponds to the fact that the varieties $V_1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid y = x^2 \}$ and $V_2 = \mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic via the polynomials maps
$$
V_1
\to V_2,
\quad (x,y)
\mapsto x
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
V_2
\to V_1,
\quad x
\mapsto (x,x^2).
$$

Comment: Is it possible to prove that kernel is zero without exhibiting an inverse map ?

Comment: @Newbie It's probably a bit over-powered, but you could use a Groebner basis computation to calculate the kernel of the map $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[t]$ with $x \mapsto t, y \mapsto t^2$ and thus show that kernel is generated by $y-x^2$.